# Fetching text from website using VBA for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am sorry if this is a very basic question, but I'm really desperate. I want to fetch the output of the website https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/78-70-6/smiles, and input it into an Excel cell using VBA. Does anyone know of a simple and straightforward way of doing this?

In a way, I would like something like "curl", in bash, but that could be used in VBA for Excel.

I'm using Excel for Mac, Version 16.16.14, with VBA 7.1.

I've tried many of the approaches suggested online, and nothing seemed to work on my version of Excel.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing you tried using Get & Transform rather than VBA first?

Are there some missing features in the mac version that make it more difficult?

Comment: Nope. The idea was to use a VBA function from the start, because that's what I know, from using numerical functions. Would those two functionalities allow the creation of a function-like operator?

Comment: Power Query/Get & Transform is the set of features in excel for importing external data through the gui.

It's relatively new, with features varying depending on version, so I'm not sure what options you have in Mac excel.

It's trivial to link to a specific web page and refresh data to a range. Setting it up to use a dynamic url is also possible, but the process varies by version.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick;

```
    Dim InternetExplorer As Object 'dim your internet explorer
    Dim WebsiteURL As String: WebsiteURL = "https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/78-70-6/smiles" 'dim and set your website url
    Dim WebsiteText As String 'dim a variable to store the website text

    Set InternetExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'set your internet explorer

    With InternetExplorer
      .Visible = 1 'set to show (if you put 0 the browser would be hidden - just remember to set to nothing at end)
      .navigate WebsiteURL 'navigates to websiteurl
       While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 'waits for page to load
         DoEvents
       Wend
    End With

    Dim WebPage As HTMLDocument 'dim your webpage as htmldocument
    Set WebPage = InternetExplorer.document 'set your webpage to the internet explorer

    WebsiteText = WebPage.body.innerText: Range("A1").Value = WebsiteText 'puts website text into variable : write to whatever cell you want
```

EDIT:
Just noticed you said for MAC - My bad as this uses internet explorer

Comment: Yep, the "InternetExplorer.Application" thing doesn't work on Mac...